# Can someone explain the difference between these two loops?

Tags: java, loops, debugging

```
   while(n>= 0 && nums[n] == value){  
        n--;
    }

   while(n>=0 && nums[n--] == value){
   }
```

I think these two loops should works exactly the same. What happens is that I run the test case input[4,5] value=4. and get an array index out of boundary. But if I can to another loop, it works.

```
public int removeElement(int[] nums, int val) {
    if(nums.length == 0) return 0;
    // use two pointers, n for the right most of the item, which value != val. 
    // i for the start pointer. 
    int n = nums.length-1;
    int i = 0;
    while(n>= 0 && nums[n--] == val){ 
    }

    while(i <= n){
        // as long as the curr items is equal to the valu
        // replace it by the right most of the value, decrement the n
        // pointer, until find another item which is not equal to val. 
        if(nums[i] == val){
            nums[i] = nums[n]; //
            while(n >= 0 && nums[--n] == val){
            }
        }
        i++;   
    }
    return n+1;
}
```

Comment: .... and what happens when you test this hypothesis?

Comment: The two loops would behave the same right now but that could change if the loops had content, depending on the placement of `n--` in the first loop relative to the loop body.

Comment: No, it seems not the same. In the first loop, if conditions hold, n gets decrement. But in the second loop, n gets decrement though the conditions do not hold.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are not the same.

In the first loop, `n` gets decremented only if `n >= 0` and `nums[n] = value`.

```
public void loop1() {
    int n = 0;
    int[] nums = new int[]{1};
    int value = 2;

    // n >= 0 is true
    // nums[n] == value is false
    // Therefore while condition is false and n is NOT decremented
    while(n>= 0 && nums[n] == value){  
        n--;
    }
    // n = 0
    System.out.println("n=" + n);
}
```

In the second loop, `n` gets decremented if `n >= 0` regardless of whether `nums[n] == value` is true or false.

```
public void loop2() {
    int n = 0;
    int[] nums = new int[]{1};
    int value = 2;

    // n >= 0 is true
    // nums[n--] == value executes in 2 steps:
    //  1.  nums[n] == value
    //  2.  n = n - 1 WILL EXECUTE regardless of result being true/false
    while(n>= 0 && nums[n--] == value){  
    }
    // n = -1
    System.out.println("n=" + n);
}
```

Comment: Unless of course the first condition is false, in which case the short-circuit would prevent n from being decremented since the second check would not happen.

Comment: really, this is wired.  What I think is n-- is firstly check the nums[n], and decrement i. If this is the case, this is same as the nums[--n]. This one will first decrement n, and then use nums[n-1].

Comment: So, whether it is because the --i or i--'s precendence is larger than the n>0 statement? So no matter whether it is true, it will perform decrease first?

Comment: You are right, nums[n--] == value will first evaluate nums[n] == value and then do n=n-1.
But the difference between the 2 loops is that the decrement of n is dependent on the result of the while condition in the first loop

Answer (score 0):

this one decrease value of n by one before execute inside statements of the loop

```
 while(n>=0 && nums[n--] == value){
```

}

this one decrease value of n by one at inside of the loop(it can be last statement or first inside statement of the loop)

```
while(n>= 0 && nums[n] == value){  
    n--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(n>= 0 && nums[n] == value){  
    n--;
}
```

That says, while n is greater than or equal to zero AND the value stored in the nums array at index n equals the variable named value, decrease n by one. If n equals 0 it will break the loop at the next iteration when n gets decreased to -1 because of the first condition where n >= 0.

```
while(n>=0 && nums[n--] == value){
}
```

This is saying while n is greater than or equal to zero AND the value stored in the nums array at index minus one, keep looping while decreasing the value of n by one.  This problem here is that when n equals 0, the first condition will be true but the second condition will fail.  That is, nums[-1] will throw the index out of bounds exception.